# Java Duration error from a day to another

Tags: java, duration, localtime

I found a very simple problem using Java Duration.

```
     LocalTime SaturdayStart = LocalTime.of(22, 30); 
     LocalTime SaturdayEnd = LocalTime.of(01, 00);
     System.out.println(SaturdayStart);
     System.out.println(SaturdayEnd);
     System.out.println(Duration.between(SaturdayStart, SaturdayEnd));
```

The output from this code is:

```
22:30
01:00
PT-21H-30M
```

And this is the problem. Instead of 21H, I wanted the duration to be 2H-30M. What is causing the method to be unable to see the "day change" between the two times?

Comment: `LocalTime` does not have a day, that is why it only has "time" in its name. There simply does not exist something like a day change in the context of LocalTime.

Comment: Maybe you were looking for `LocalDateTime` .

Comment: It doesn't return 21H but MINUS 21H, which ***is*** the difference between 22:30 and 01:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `LocalTime` just represents a single time, in *one* day, without a time zone.

Since it represents the time you see on the clock in *one* day, you can't use it to calculate differences between 22:30 *today* and 01:00 *the next day*. Your two `LocalTime` object represent 22:30 *today*, and 01:00 *today* respectively.

To take the day into account, you need a `LocalDateTime`. This represents not only a time (without a time zone), but also the date in the ISO-8601 calendar system. You can create the two `LocalDateTime` objects like this:

```
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.of(22, 30));
LocalDateTime end = start.plusDays(1).withHour(1).withMinute(0);
```

And then you can get the duration:

```
Duration d = Duration.between(start, end);
System.out.println(d);
```

By the way, the `-` characters you get in your wrong output are not delimiters for different components. They are negative signs. This is because you are subtracting 22:30 from 01:00, which is like subtracting a bigger number from a smaller number, you get a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

The returned `Duration` interval has data, whether the `StartTime` occurs after `EndTime` or not, which can be used for further processing; like this

```
     LocalTime SaturdayStart = LocalTime.of(22, 30); 
     LocalTime SaturdayEnd = LocalTime.of(01, 00);
     System.out.println(SaturdayStart);
     System.out.println(SaturdayEnd);
     Duration interval = Duration.between(SaturdayStart, SaturdayEnd);
     interval = interval.isNegative() ? interval.plusDays(1) : interval;
     System.out.println(interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) and `PT-21H-30M` means a duration of `21` hours and `30` minutes where the minus sign indicates that the end time is earlier than the start time. Therefore, you can not get what you want unless you consider a date with time and the type representing both, date and time is `LocalDateTime`. You can choose any date and combine it with a time to get a `LocalDateTime`.

For any given date, if the start time is after the end time, reset the end date-time to midnight, then add one day to it and finally set its time to the end time.

Once you have the duration, you can create a formatted string by getting the hours, minutes, seconds etc. from it. With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced which makes it easier.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.of(22, 30);
        LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.of(01, 00);

        LocalDateTime startDateTime = today.atTime(startTime);
        LocalDateTime endDateTime = today.atTime(endTime);

        if (startDateTime.isAfter(endDateTime)) {
            endDateTime = endDateTime.with(LocalTime.MIN).plusDays(1).with(endTime);
        }

        Duration duration = Duration.between(startDateTime, endDateTime);
        // Default format
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedDuration = String.format("%dH-%dM-%dS", duration.toHours(), duration.toMinutes() % 60,
                duration.toSeconds() % 60);
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedDuration = String.format("%dH-%dM-%dS", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(),
                duration.toSecondsPart());
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT2H30M
2H-30M-0S
2H-30M-0S
```